# Quote a value of constant without double quotes in javadoc

Tags: javadoc

I can use below expression to reference a constant field in JavaDoc across classes

`<td>{@value com.balin.e2etest.support.ParameterMapKeys#INUM_TR_URL}</td>`

However, the rendered page presents

```
"inum_tr_url"
```

with double quotes around the value which i want to eliminate. I googled for a while with no luck. Any helps?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I too would like to not have the quotes, they become a distraction when there are many @value tags